# Difference between topological components and connected components?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials

Why are the following results different?

(1) Let $p$ be a polynomial in $n$ variables with real coefficients. The set of points $(x_1,...,x_n)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ at which p vanishes will be denoted by $N(p)$. If the degree of $p$ is $d$, then the number of **topological components** of $N(p)$ does not exceed $2d^n$. (from Lemma 2.5 [here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/06c1/26b1238dc11cc1e36a3b876dab4044637fa1.pdf))

(2) Let $V$ be a real variety in $\mathbb{R}^n$, denoted by the solution set of the real polynomial equations $f_i(x_1,...,x_n)=0, (i=1,2,...,m)$, and suppose the degree of each polynomial $f_i$ is at most $d$. Then the number of **connected components** of $V$ is at most $d(2d - 1)^{n-1}$. (from Theorem 5.1 [here](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/%7Enogaa/PDFS/tools1.pdf))

I am confused why the two results are different. In my understanding, in (2), if we let $\sum_{i=1}^mf^2_i(x_1,...,x_n)=0$, we should obtain the result as $2(2d)^n$. Is there any difference between topological components and connected components in above text?

Comment: I haven't seen this terminology much and might be totally wrong, but I think what's going on here is that topological components means connected components in the Zariski topology, not connected components in the Hausdorff topology. To see that these are different, consider the real points of $y^2=x^3-x$ ([link to graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/swi09xdhtg)). This polynomial is irreducible, hence it's solution set is irreducible in the Zariski topology, but it has two connected components in the Hausdorff topology.

Comment: From the context, they mean the same thing. The fact that by looking at the sum of squares you obtained a worse bound is not at all surprising: Milnor's inequality used by Alon is sharper.

Comment: @KReiser I have tried to understand the Zariski topology, but there are more and more jargon appear making me confused. Could you explain this in a simpler language?

Comment: Let me preface this by saying that Moishe's indicated that the two terms mean the same thing here with much more certainty than I've got, and I'm inclined to believe what he's written. Anyways, the point is that the solutions of $y^2=x^3-x$ have two connected components in the Euclidean topology: you can see them in the graph above. On the other hand, in the Zariski topology, the closed sets are the vanishing locii of ideals of polynomials, and there's no polynomial which vanishes on one of those two Euclidean connected components but not the other. That's all that's going on.